¿cómo puedo hacer que aparezca el item 0 y llenado los jtextfield no editable al solo abrir mi GUI? Eclipse
Buenas estoy haciendo un proyecto de una GUI, recien soy novato y no se mucho, por favor si alguien me ayuda.cuando la caja diálogo se haga visible deberán verse inmediatamente los datos del primera Etiqueta del Combobox
osea al abrirlo, me aparezca el primer ITEM, y abajo en los txtfields me salgan sus datos del primer item, solo al abrir la GUI.
EN ECLIPSE, JAVA



Recuerda colocar siempre el código y los mensajes de error como texto, con formato. No todos pueden ver las imágenes, además de que no se puede copypastear una imagen :) Si te aparece el error de que la pregunta "es solo código": 1. Recuerda solo agregar el código relevante; 2. si aún así aparece el error, coloca el código sin formato, y alguien editará tu pregunta para que se vea como corresponde; 3. ¡No olvides ser descriptivo en la pregunta! Explica a detalle qué quieres hacer. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

no no.. @padaleiana no es poner el codigo como texto porque si.. si es mucho codigo, seguramente la pregunta esta mal formulada y el codigo sobra...

@gbianchi Claro que sí, faltó mencionar que debe ser un [repro].

"2. si aún así aparece el error, coloca el código sin formato, y alguien editará tu pregunta para que se vea como corresponde;" esto es un NO rotundo..

bienvenido, si no entiendo erróneamente tu pregunta, en el constructor de tu gui, deberías tener algo como:
String items[] = {
   "Mabe EMP6120PGO",
   "Indurama Parma", 
   "Sole COSOL027", 
   ...
};
  // instancias el **combo** pasandole como argumento el array con los item's a mostrar
cmbModelo = new JComboBox( items );
  // seteas los **textfield** con los argumentos iniciales
textPrecios.setText( "949.0" );
textAncho.setText( "60.0" );
textAlto.setText( "91.0" );
textFondo.setText( "58.6" );
textQuemadores.setText( "4" );
...

El actionListener, ejecutará el código del actionPerformed cuando ejecutes alguna acción sobre el mismo.
Si tienes alguna duda, pregunta en los comentarios, antes, edita tu pregunta, elimina la imagen, y agrega el código como texto, así evitarás el cierre de la misma.
